# WAMP- localhost opening error

Tags: wamp

I am trying to install wamp server (following is the exact setup name) on windows 7, 64Bit OS. But it never starts, icon stays in green color meaning services start.but it is not working.

Comment: What error you are getting then??

Comment: Change the skype port if you've.

Comment: clarify with relevant info.

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities

WAMP use port 80 : Is there any other process running which might use port 80. Skype use this port. Do you have skype ?

If the Wampmanager icon in the system tray is Orange then one of the services has not started.

Look at your MySQL error log and Windows Event Viewer, for error messages from MySQL, that should tell you what the problem is.

If you tried installing Apache and MySQL independantly before you installed WAMPServer make sure they are both properly uninstalled. Also check there is no my.ini file anywhere on your system except inside the C:\wamp folder structure.